# Radio button not honoring checked state when inside a custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The problem is this: when I check Male or Female, both of them get checked. Earlier, the simpler way of using v-model didn't cause this issue.

Also, advise me on whether I can shove @toparent somewhere inside the component than outside? But that's a side question if you have time.

Here is the component.

```
Vue.component('singleselect', {
    template: `
    <div>
        <p class="form__answer">
            <input type="radio" :id="meta.id" :value="meta.value" @click="notifyParent($event.target.value)"
            <label :for="meta.id">
                {{ meta.value }}
            </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        notifyParent(selected) {
            this.$emit('toparent', {type: this.meta.type, data: selected});
        }
    },
    props: {
        meta: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }

    }
});
```

Here is the usage:

```
<singleselect @toparent="inbound($event)" :meta="{type: 'gender', id: 'male', value: 'Male'}"></singleselect>
<singleselect @toparent="inbound($event)" :meta="{type: 'gender', id: 'female', value: 'Female'}"></singleselect>
```

Answer (score 3):

> A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group
> the **same name**. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio
> button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected
> radio button in the same group.
>
> From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

You inputs have **no name**. They **don't have v-model** to control them either. So nothing is stopping them from being checked at the same time.

---

For the side question, you can pass `inbound` as a property like this

```
<singleselect :inbound="inbound"></singleselect>
```

And then do this in the component

```
export default {
  methods: {
    notifyParent(selected) {
      this.inbound({ type: this.meta.type, data: selected });
    }
  },
  props: {
    //   ...
    inbound: {
      type: Function,
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

make sense ?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Had to utilize a new feature in Vue 2.2.0+ `model`.

**Markup**

```
<radio v-model="form.gender" id="male" value="Male" name="sex"></radio>
<radio v-model="form.gender" id="female" value="Female" name="sex"></radio>
```

**Component**

```
Vue.component('radio', {
    model: {
        prop: 'checked',
        event: 'change'
      },
    template: `
    <div>
        <p class="form__answer">
            <input type="radio" :id="id" :value="value" :name="name" @change="update">
            <label :for="id">
                {{ value }}
            </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        update(e) {
            this.$emit('change', this.value);
          }
    },
    props: {
        value: null,
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

The data still gets to the parent via `v-model` like normal.

As Jacob Goh said, `name` attribute was key.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been said *in-between the lines* of the above answers. However, I want to highlight this issue.

In my case, I had a group of radio buttons in a component like this:

[image: Image of radio button group]

To limit only one of the three buttons to be checked at the time, I had to add the same name to the three of the radio inputs:

```HTML
<input type="radio" v-model="status" value="rejected" id="rejected" name="status">
<label class="rejected" for="rejected">Avvist</label>

<input type="radio" v-model="status" value="ongoing" id="ongoing" name="status">
<label class="ongoing" for="ongoing">Pågår</label>

<input type="radio" v-model="status" value="done" id="done" name="status">
<label class="done" for="done">Utført</label>
```

This is by the book, the correct way to do it. However, this way actually makes all of the components have the same radio group. This means that if `rejected` is selected, the browser does not know which of the inputs with value `rejected` to toggle, making all un-toggled.

The solution is to simply add a unique name to each of the components.

```HTML
<input type="radio" v-model="status" value="rejected" :id="'rejected'+someUniqueId" :name="'status'" + someUniqueId>
<label class="rejected" :for="'rejected'+someUniqueId">Avvist</label>
```

I hope this saves someone debugging time.